# Leaks through top of windshield replacement

Tags: dodge, windshield, water-leak, caliber

2010 Dodge Caliber, had its windshield replaced over two years ago.  In heavy rain water will actually drip from several places along the front headliner and map light cover.

Isn't the top of the windshield supposed to have a gasket of some sort?  I.e., is there a piece of trim missing that would explain this leak?  Here's a photo of passenger side – kind of hard to see, but the top edge of the glass is exposed:

[image: Windshield top on 2010 Dodge Caliber]

In any case, what would be the most effective or expedient way to seal the top of this windshield against water (without removing the glass)?

Comment: Who put the windshield in? More than likely, they have a lifetime seal warranty on their work. If it leaks, they should be doing it for free. Other than removing the windshield, there is not "sure fire" way of fixing the leak. You can poke more sealant at it, but more than likely it won't cure your car's leak.